# If ΔABC has area 15 cm^2: find the area of ΔCDE, find the area of PQED

Tags: triangles, area

I have a similar triangle question that has got me stumped:
[image: Diagram]

I have already worked out question a)

(Let $x$ = area of $∆CDE$）

$$ \frac{x}{15} =(8/5)^2$$

$$ \frac{x}{15} =64/25$$

$$ x=64/25*15$$

$$x=38.4$$

But I can’t seem to work out part b). Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Find the area of $\triangle CPQ$ and do the subtraction.

Comment: @CYAries How can I with all of the unknowns?

Comment: You have $CQ=\frac{1}{2}CE$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already noticed that the triangles are similar.

In similar triangles, if their lengths differ by a factor of $r$, their areas differ by a factor of $r^2$.

Let's use this!

The ratio of sides of $\triangle DEC$ to $\triangle ABC$ is $\displaystyle \frac{8}{5}$.

Therefore, the area of $\triangle DEC$ is $\displaystyle 15\left(\frac{8}{5}\right)^2=\boxed{38.4}$

Similarly, notice that by the Midpoint Theorem, $PQ=4$, so the ratio of sides of $\triangle PQC$ to $\triangle ABC$ is $\displaystyle \frac{4}{5}$.

Therefore, the area of $\triangle PQC$ is $\displaystyle 15\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^2=\boxed{9.6}$

---

I will explain how I figured out that $PQ=4$ a bit more.

Notice that by the Midpoint Theorem, we have $CQ=QE$.

Therefore, $\displaystyle CQ=\frac{1}{2}CE$.

Because the triangles $CQP$ and $CED$ are similar, we have the ratio of the sides of $CQP$ to $CED$ is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}$, so directly applying that to $DE$ and $PQ$ gives $\displaystyle PQ = \frac{1}{2}DE = 4$.

---

Forgot to answer your last question.

The area of PQED is the difference of the areas of $\triangle DEC$ and $\triangle PQC$, as you can see. This is $38.4 - 9.6 = \boxed{28.8}$.